# Startup script for a docker container

Tags: shell, docker

I have a docker container already running. I have made some configuration changes, let's say have added some host info in /etc/hosts inside the container. How do I keep the changes saved, so that next time when I open an interactive shell to the container I don't have to do the same stuff again ? For now I have created a mini script as addhosts.sh as below inside the container and have to run it every time.

```
echo "1.2.3.4 server1.example.com gluster1" >> /etc/hosts
echo "5.6.7.8 server2.example.com gluster2" >> /etc/hosts
```

This is one of the cases. Similarly, I need all my configuration to be intact. Please don't suggest for dockerfile as I'm not creating an image rather I'm just getting into the container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can commit the changes you made by:

Short Command reference:

```
docker commit <container id or name>  <repository name>/<your image name>:<tage aka version>
```

Example:

```
docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3
```

Full Reference:

```
Usage:  docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Create a new image from a container's changes

Options:
  -a, --author string    Author (e.g., "John Hannibal Smith <hannibal@a-team.com>")
  -c, --change value     Apply Dockerfile instruction to the created image (default [])
      --help             Print usage
  -m, --message string   Commit message
  -p, --pause            Pause container during commit (default true)
```

Then you can use `docker images` to view your new Image after commit.

To run a container from your new Image:

`docker run -d svendowideit/testimage:version3 <optional startup command>`

Another way would be creating your own image via: `dockerfile`, I'm Just putting it here just incase we can help others.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Is it also applicable to exited containers ? Coz my container has exited. I did docker commit for the container and then exited, started and attached it. But I don't see my configurations intact.

Comment: How do you start your container? You should include the created version. As for the example `docker run svendowideit/testimage:version3`

Comment: By running below:

`docker start 44372579f2ea`
`docker attach 44372579f2ea`

Comment: Where did you get this ID 44372579f2ea ?

Comment: You can commit exited containers, I tried the following : `sudo docker run -d debian:jessie /bin/touch /test1` then checked the container, it was exited. after that I did the commit: `sudo docker commit 32f8ea080748 test1/test1:latest` and I start a new container using the new commited image: `sudo docker run -di test1/test1:latest /bin/bash ` and I used `docker exec for checking my file: `sudo docker exec -it b3b24954e9f1 /bin/ls ` ad my file is there.

Comment: Just make sure you connect to your new container not the old one!! use `sudo docker ps` to get the new containers ID

Comment: Great, this works. Just a quick question, if I do some changes to any conf files from inside the container (unlike using docker run with touch), will the above solution work ?

Comment: As long as you dont mount volumes on them , this should work.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you do not wish to save the changes into a new image:

```
docker exec -it container_id echo "1.2.3.4 server1.example.com gluster1" >> /etc/hosts
docker exec -it container_id echo "5.6.7.8 server2.example.com gluster2" >> /etc/hosts
```

That would connect to the container, run the command and exit without killing the container.

Notice the difference between the following:

```
docker exec -it container_id ... = does not kill the container. 
docker run -it container_id   ...= kills the container
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `docker commit` to take a snapshot of your container.

```
Usage:  docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Create a new image from a container's changes

Options:
  -a, --author string    Author (e.g., "John Hannibal Smith <hannibal@a-team.com>")
  -c, --change value     Apply Dockerfile instruction to the created image (default [])
      --help             Print usage
  -m, --message string   Commit message
  -p, --pause            Pause container during commit (default true)
```

`Example: docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3`

Have look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

To **run a snapshot** of a docker container add the version to run command. As for the example run
`docker run svendowideit/testimage:version3`